# Android Location API vs geolocation-API

Tags: android, geolocation

I am a new bee to mobile programming.

1. What is the different between

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Vs

http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/

2.If I want my mobile users to send information like latitude , user profile information to

server through Web service what should be the best approach ?

3.Is it possible to use http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/ track locations of Android applications

Answer (score 0):

Both can do. Its based on what u use.

- If u use Android API (Java) you have a couple of options to get the current location.
- When u use JavaScript use this geolocation API that u mentioned.

Comment: 3.Is it possible to use http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/ track locations of Android applications? instead of  android.location.LocationListener;
android.location.LocationManager;

Comment: The API is in javascript. U can use this script to detect the location. But I dont understand the term "Location of Android Application"

Comment: Assume I need to develop application to track the location. The platform can be anything  PC , Tab , Mobile. Based on the feedback Geolocation-API is the good as Java script does not have any limitation. I wanted to demonstrate this in Android platform as for the proof of concept. I am worrying to use java script as thinking about security. Because finally  user needs to pass some information to the server with location details.

Comment: If its a website or should it be platform independent, you use the JS GeoLocation API. This JavaScript would retrieve the Location only. The security aspects on sending data is independent. U retrieve the data and encrypt and send to server. However, if its an application u need in device, u may decide to go native.